# automatic selected dropdown date PHP (with joomla)

Tags: php, date, drop-down-menu, joomla, selected

at first sorry for my english. I have a problem with my website. I have 2 dropdown with date [see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYrTX.png) (inizio=start, fine=end). I would like that when I click the START DATE, the END DATE changes (automatically) to one hour more than the start date. For example: In "inizio" I select the following date: 16 agosto (August) 2017 **14**:30, the END DATE should changes automatically in 16 agosto 2017 **15**:30. Default.php:

```
<tr height="50px">
        <td align="center" style="border-color:white; border:0px; background-color:#F8F9FA;"><br /><b><font size="+1">Inizio</font></b></td>
        <td align="center" style="border-color:white; border:0px; background-color:#F8F9FA;"><br />' . $this->helper->dateTimePicker("inizio", "DATETIME") . '</td>
    </tr>

    <tr height="50px">
        <td align="center" style="border-color:white; border:0px; background-color:#F8F9FA;"><b><font size="+1">Fine</font></b></td>
        <td align="center" style="border-color:white; border:0px; background-color:#F8F9FA;">' . $this->helper->dateTimePicker("fine", "DATETIME") . '</td>
    </tr>
```

Method dataTimePicker:

```
    function dateTimePicker($dpname, $mode = "DATE") // MODES: "DATE" or "DATETIME"
{
    $control = "";
    $anni_da_visualizzare = 2;

    if ($mode == "DATE" || $mode == "DATETIME")
    {

        $control .= '<select name="giorno_'.$dpname.'">';

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++)
        {
            if ($i == date("j"))
            {
               $control .=  '<option value="'.$i.'" selected="selected">'.$i.'</option>';
            }
            else
            {
               $control .=  '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
            }
        }

        $control .= '</select>';
        //=================================

        $control .= "&nbsp;";

                $mesi = array("Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre");

        $control .= '<select name="mese_'.$dpname.'">';

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++)
        {
            if ($i == date("n"))
            {
               $control .=  '<option value="'.$i.'" selected="selected">'.$mesi[$i-1].'</option>';
            }
            else
            {
               $control .=  '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$mesi[$i-1].'</option>';
            }
        }

        $control .= '</select>';
        //=================================

        $control .= "&nbsp;";


        $control .= '<select name="anno_'.$dpname.'">';

        $inizio = date("Y");
        $fine = date("Y") + $anni_da_visualizzare;


        for ($i = $inizio; $i <= $fine; $i++)
        {
            if ($i == date("Y"))
            {
               $control .=  '<option value="'.$i.'" selected="seected">'.$i.'</option>';
            }
            else
            {
                $control .=  '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
            }
        }

        $control .= '</select>';
        //=================================

        $control .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";


        if ($mode == "DATETIME")
        {
            //H - ore_$dpname !
            $control .= '<select name="ore_'.$dpname.'">';

            for ($i = 0; $i <= 23; $i++)
            {
               if ($i == date("G"))
               {
                   $control .=  '<option value="'.$i.'" selected="selected">'.($i < 0 ? '0'.$i : $i).'</option>';
               }



               else
               {
                  $control .=  '<option value="'.$i.'">'.($i < 10 ? '0'.$i : $i).'</option>';
               }
            }

            $control .= '</select>';
            //=================================

            $control .= "&nbsp;";

            //Minutes- minuti_$dpname !
            $control .= '<select name="minuti_'.$dpname.'">';

            for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++)
            {

                if (intval(date("i")) < ($i*15) && intval(date("i")) > (($i*15) - 15))
                    $control .=  '<option value="'.($i*15).'" selected="selected">'.($i == 0 ? '00' : (15*$i)).'</option>';
                else
                    $control .=  '<option value="'.($i*15).'">'.($i == 0 ? '00' : (15*$i)).'</option>';
            }

            $control .= '</select>';
            //=================================

            $control .= "&nbsp;";
        }

        return $control."<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        return "{<u>dateTimePicker ERROR:</u> modalit&agrave; non valida}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val)

It would be best to use jquery for this. You would have to add something like `$(".time2").val('2');` within the onchange of time1. Where the amount in val is equal to the time plus 1 hour.

Time1 - being the first date and time class
Time2 - being the second date and time class